# Bash Store Curl Results into Array

Tags: arrays, bash, curl

I am running the following curl command:

```
results=$(curl -USERNAME:PASSWORD "URL/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Three_Months_Ago}&today&repos=generic-sgca")
echo "$results"
```

I am getting this in return:

```
"results" : [ {
    "uri" : "URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Lastest_Deploy.tar",
    "created" : "2017-09-14T11:59:14.483-06:00"
  }, {
    "uri" : "URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.5/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-linux-x64-installer.run",
    "created" : "2017-09-14T20:11:37.733-06:00"
  }
```

It doesn't seem to actually be storing the curl results as an array. I want to be able to store each "uri" as a variable and use an "-X DELETE" command to remove each file. How can I get the "uri" line on it's own, remove the "created" option.

EDIT:

I've used the following command:

```
results=$(curl -username:password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Three_Months_Ago}&today&repos=generic-sgca" | jq -r '.results[].uri')
echo "$results"
```

I got this in return:

```
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Lastest_Deploy.tar
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.5/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.5/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.99/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.99/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.2.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.2.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-100.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-100.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-101.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-101.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.9/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.9/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.91/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.91/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
```

Now I want to run a curl -X DELETE command to delete each of those urls from my Artifactory page. The command would be:

```
curl username:password -X DELETE "URL FROM ABOVE"
```

But I can't figure out how to store each line as a separate variable so I can delete each one.

Comment: It doesn't seem to because it *isn't*. You are just saving a single JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

Use `jq` to extract the URLs.

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.results[].uri'
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Lastest_Deploy.tar
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.5/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Then use your favorite correct technique for iterating over the output of a command line-by-line; see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for details.

(I'm assuming a URL will not contain a newline; if that's the case, switch to a different language that can handle arbitrary data more easily.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated my OP. Mind taking a look? Need help storing each line as separate variables so I can delete each URL.

Comment: Did you look at Bash FAQ 001 yet?